# Compare 2 column and arrange values in 3rd column in excel

Tags: excel

i have 2 columns A and B and want to  compare values in both column. I want final result in below format e.g A has 78 and B has 78 also, 78 will be in C column where A 78 value is present.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oFfO.png)

Comment: No question, no attempt made... I'm sorry but telling us you want something is not enough. Look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Edit your question and we will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

khaleel hussain.

Put this formula in C2 (change "$B$40" to the last cell in your B column):

`=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$40,0)>0,A2),"N/A")`

I hope it helps you...